# How to auto calculate fields in django?

Tags: jquery, django

This is my model:

```
class Stockdata(models.Model):
    quantity    = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    rate        = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,default=0.00)
    opening     = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,default=0.00)
    stock_name  = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

I want to do something like:
`opening = quantity * rate` in my django form template.

I have tried the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id_Quantity').keyup(function() {
        var a = $('#id_rate').val();
        var b = $(this).val();
        $('#id_opening').val(a * b);
    });
});

</script>
```

But it is not not giving ne the result

My template:

```
            <form method="POST">

      <div class="form-group row">

                <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Stock Name<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:16px;color:red">*</i></label>

                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                    {{ form.stock_name.errors }}
                        {{ form.stock_name }}
                    </div>
                </div>
           <div class="form-group row">

                <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Quantity<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:16px;color:red">*</i></label>

                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                    {{ form.Quantity.errors }}
                    {{ form.Quantity }}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">

                <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Rate<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:16px;color:red">*</i></label>

                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                    {{ form.rate.errors }}
                    {{ form.rate }}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">

                <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Opening Balance<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:16px;color:red">*</i></label>

                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                    {{ form.opening.errors }}
                    {{ form.opening }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Any one have any idea about how to perform this?
Actually I am very much new to jquery so having some basic problems.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'll advise not to perform the calculation on the front end and post the data to the backend (unless you need to show the value of `opening` to the user).

Instead, you should calculate the `opening` value on save in your `Stockdata` django model, by simply overriding the `save` method. This has been shown below.

```
class Stockdata(models.Model):
    quantity    = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    rate        = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,default=0.00)
    opening     = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,default=0.00)
    stock_name  = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    # you override the save method and calculate for opening
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.opening = self.quantity * self.rate;
        super(Stockdata, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**N.B**
If you still need to show the user the opening value while they input the quantity value and rate values, you'll need to make some modifications to your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id_Quantity').keyup(function() {
        var rate = parseFloat($('#id_rate').val());
        var quantity = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        $('#id_opening').text(rate * quantity);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Then your html section would be:

```
<form method="POST">

  <div class="form-group row">

    <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Stock Name<i class="material-icons"
        style="font-size:16px;color:red">*</i></label>

    <div class="col-lg-10">
      {{ form.stock_name.errors }}
      {{ form.stock_name }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">

    <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Quantity<i class="material-icons"
        style="font-size:16px;color:red">*</i></label>

    <div class="col-lg-10">
      {{ form.Quantity.errors }}
      {{ form.Quantity }}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">

    <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Rate<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:16px;color:red">*</i></label>

    <div class="col-lg-10">
      {{ form.rate.errors }}
      {{ form.rate }}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">

    <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Opening Balance<i class="material-icons"
        style="font-size:16px;color:red">*</i></label>

    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <!-- opening value will be displayed here -->
      <label id="id_opening"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Its not working...I tried...The result is coming `0`

Comment: Are you getting the  `0`  result from the database?

Answer (score 0):

There is an django app that facilitates the calculation in the frontend by writing the expression in the definition of the form widget.

**[django-calculation](https://github.com/blasferna/django-calculation)** you can get it with:

```sh
pip install django-calculation
```

An example of how you could achieve the calculation simply by defining an expression in a ModelForm.

```py
from django import forms

# import your Stockdata model
from .models import Stockdata

# import the calculation module from django-calculation app
import calculation

# create a ModelForm of you Stockdata model
class StockdataForm(forms.ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = Stockdata
        fields = ['quantity', 'rate', 'opening', 'stock_name']
        # define a custom widget to your opening field
        widgets = {
            'opening': calculation.FormulaInput('rate*quantity')
        }
```

be sure to include `{{ form.media }}` in your template.